# Put a string before a certain string inside a text in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm dealing with an issue here, I have a URL of an image which is like this

`http://example.com/image/test.jpg`

Which is a string.

And I would like to insert before `.jpg` a certain text like `-40x40`

Is there any way to analyze the URL string and somehow to add this text so the final string should be

`http://example.com/image/text-40x40.jpg`

What i've tried till now is this

```
var finalImage = "http://example.com/image/test.jpg"
finalImage.insert("-40x40" as Character, at: finalImage.endIndex - 4)
```

but i get 2 errors.

1) i cant add more than 1 character and 2) i cant do the math ad endIndex.

But i can't add more than one character there.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It uses `NSURL`, which exists so that path manipulations are easy and legal! The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl) is really quite good.

```
let s1 = "http://example.com/image/test.jpg"
let u = URL(fileURLWithPath: s1)
let exExt = u.deletingPathExtension()
let s2 = exExt.absoluteString + "-40x40.jpg"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another ways.

The code shown in the question, fixed:

```
var finalImage = "http://example.com/image/test.jpg"
let extIndex = finalImage.index(finalImage.endIndex, offsetBy: -4)
finalImage.insert(contentsOf: "-40x40".characters, at: extIndex)
```

Using `NSRegularExpression`:

```
let origImage = "http://example.com/image/test.jpg"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\.jpg)$", options: .caseInsensitive)
let finalImage = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: origImage, range: NSRange(0..<origImage.utf16.count), withTemplate: "-40x40$0")
```

Answer (score 2):

Grimxn's solution is probably the best fit for this problem, but for more complex manipulation of URLs, take a look at the `NSURLComponents` class. You can convert an NSURL to `NSURLComponents`, then use the various methods of `NSURLComponents` to manipulate your URL, and then finally convert the `NSURLComponents` back to an `NSURL`

As noted in a comment by @dfri, Swift 3 (and later) includes a native `URLComponents` class, which follows Swift naming and calling conventions. Going forward you should use that instead of the Objective-C/Swift 2 `NSURLComponents` class.

Comment: +1 for this, just a prompt: in Swift 3, we needn't really mention `NSUrlComponents`, as we will only work with the native [`URLComponents` (a structure bridging to the former Obj-C class)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcomponents).

Comment: I figured as much, but I've been developing for a client using Swift 2, and haven't made the switch to Swift 3 yet, so I didn't want to misstate.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to the neat [accepted answer by @Grimxn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39931677/4573247): [Foundation's `URL`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url) has various more methods that allows for more separation "of concerns" in case you'd like to apply some more complex modification of the image (file) name, while not really worrying about the image (file) name extension.

```
let s1 = "http://example.com/something.cgi/image/test.jpg"
let u = URL(fileURLWithPath: s1)

// separate into (String) components of interest
let prefixUrl = u.deletingLastPathComponent().absoluteString 
    // "http://example.com/something.cgi/image/"
let fileName = u.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent   
    // "test"
let fileExtension = "." + u.pathExtension                    
    // ".jpg"

// ... some methods that implements your possibly more 
// complex filename modification
func modify(fileName fName: String) -> String {
    // ...
    return fName + "-40x40"
}

// reconstruct url with modified filename
let s2 = prefixUrl + modify(fileName: fileName) + fileExtension
print(s2) // http:/example.com/something.cgi/image/test-40x40.jpg
```

Comment: I almost put this into my answer, but favoured brevity. Thanks for "completing" my answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/image/test.jpg"),withoutExt = url.URLByDeletingPathExtension
{
       let finalstring : NSString = withoutExt.absoluteString + "-40x40.jpg"
       print(finalstring)
}
```

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios R u Using swift 3.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Very simply with one line...

```
let newURL = oldURL.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".jpg", withString: "-40x40.jpg", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```